# Add windows encoding to Eclipse on linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, encoding

I have a legacy project which has all the source files, templates, properties written in cp1250 encoding. (Windows 1250 - central european). Recently I switched from Windows to Ubuntu and found out, that fresh installation of Eclipse 3.5 doesn't have cp1250 in neither project properties nor workspace settings. How do I install new encoding to be recognised by Eclipse?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now that's just typical, a minute later I send the question I find out that the drop-down menu can be also edited, so it's just simply matter of writing cp1250 in there, hitting OK and voila, problem solved. Eclipse even rerenders opened editors to show applied encoding right away. Problem solved.

Comment: "it's just simply matter of writing cp1250 in there" Tell us. How?

Comment: +1, I was just about to ask the exact same thing here. Damn those editable dropdowns.

Comment: Dropdown is editable and accepts any value that is recognized by Java file encoding.

Comment: In my experience, the encoding of a project in windows actually works better with iso-8859-1 than cp1250, some characters (like 'ã') didn't read correctly with cp1250 for me.

Comment: @elias The encoding `cp1250` is used for Central European languages. For Western languages, Windows use [`cp1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which has just a few differences from ISO-8859-1.